# If I change a div's HTML with jQuery, all DOM elements and listeners removed from memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm thinking if I override a div's html with the jQuery html() method all 'old' DOM elements and all listeners removed from the memory?

For example:

HTML:

```
<div id='aDiv'>
    <div id='anANotherDiv'>An Another Div</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('anANotherDiv').click(function(){
    var b='An Another Div'
    console.log(b);
});


$('#aDiv').html('<div id='oDiv'>This div override the another</div>');
$('#oDiv').click(function(){
    var a='This div override the another';
    console.log(a);
});
```

So when I overrid the old the GC will be delete the old DOM elements and listeners?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Do you want a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay !! Lets start from this way .

Here is your HTML

```
<div id='aDiv'>
      <div id='anANotherDiv'>An Another Div</div>
</div>
```

Now `aDiv` is containing only one `div` as it's child and it is `anANotherDiv` . Now when you go for this on your console

```
 $("#adIV").html();
```

The console output will be

```
<div id='anANotherDiv'>An Another Div</div>
```

Now when you go for something like this on your console

```
$('#aDiv').html('<div id=\"oDiv\">This div override the another</div>');
```

The console output will be only

```
<div id="oDiv">This div override the another</div>
```

You are actually `manipulating` completely the entire `aDiv` strucuture . `.html()` basically `changes` the HTML structure . So you need to make sure whether you want to completely change the `HTML` structure of a particular `element` or `node` or you just have to `append` or `do some other stuffs`

Hope I am clear to you .

Cheers !!

Comment: It's clear, thanks for your answer. And what's wrong with the javascript variables and event listeners? I need "destroy" something, or not?

Comment: whatever DOM elements inside will be lost . If this is clear to you ,kindly accept my answer so that it is beneficial for others also .

Comment: The javascript variables and event listeners are not the part of DOM elements . There you need to use jQuery functions for any action . Like you want to remove , use `.remove()` .There are lots of functions available .You can check the jQuery `API`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on` method from jQuery, you can use it to bind the event with reference to parent element so even if you change the actual target DIV's content, event will get attached as we have bind event with reference to parent element.

```
//Example:
<div id='aDiv'>
    <div id='anANotherDiv'>An Another Div</div>
</div>


$(function(){
   $("#aDiv").on("click", "div", function(){
      var a='This div override the another';
      console.log(a);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve event listeners problem, I usually use "global click" approach ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aaq7ure/1/)):

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" data-clickable>
    Parent Click
    <div id="div2" data-clickable>
        Child ClickClicks
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document.body).click(function(e){
    var n="[data-clickable]", $t = $(e.target).is(n) ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).parents(n+":first");

    switch ($t.attr('id')){ 
        case 'div1':
            console.debug("DIV1 clicked");
            break;
        case 'div2':
            console.debug("DIV2 clicked");
            break;
    }

});
```

It listens to body's clicks, and then decides if that was the click we are waiting for.
As for elements replacement problem, there is nothing you can do. You have to come up with some other approach rather than `.html()`